# Should I use Sprung or Sprang?

Tags: word-choice

I just finished my English language exam, and it had the following sentence:

> Beads of sweat sprang from his skin

Should it really be sprang? I always thought it was sprung, but I guess they are both valid?

Or is it like effect and affect, and they are used in different places?

Comment: If it's like effect and affect, then the meanings are completely different and not at all interchangeable.

Comment: _Sprang_ is the usual choice for the past tense, but as AHDEL and RHK Webster's state, _sprung_ is an acceptable alternative. I think Collins tries to say the same thing. There are some authorities who think that AHDEL and RHK Webster's are wrong here.

Comment: There is a tendency for strong verbs with the _ring, rang, rung_ 1-2-3 pattern to follow the _wring, wrung, wrung_ 1-2-2 pattern, often dialectally. The prime example is the Disney movie title _Honey, I Shrunk the Kids_, where _shrank_ is the more traditional past tense form.

Comment: @JohnLawler That's why it sounded odd to me? Because people often use the sprung when they shouldn't?

Comment: It might be. It's your language, so only you can say why you got that impression.

Comment: @Tim: If I were editing a document that was intended for general consumption, a written piece which was not a personal diary and not a work of fiction, I'd correct *sprung* to *sprang* as nonstandard, just as I'd correct "He rung the bell" to "He rang the bell".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Sprang* is the past tense:

> Beads of sweat **sprang** from his skin.

*Sprung* is the past participle:

> Beads of sweat **have sprung** from his skin.

Some dictionaries list *sprung* as an acceptable past form as well, but others list only *sprang*. [Reverso Conjugator](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-spring.html) gives lists of the commonly accepted conjugations of *[to] spring*,  if you're interested.